# Custom user and custom permission in linux

Tags: linux, unix, admin

I've this need, I have to install ubuntu on a machine for a specific purpose, and I have to create a particular locked user account.

On startup i need to display the login box (so I have to admin the machine, only reboot and login as root) in the format with username and password fields.

After the login of this user, I have to auto open Google Chrome on a specific page.

Stop, this specific user doesn't have to do more. This machine is connected to a display with show ads in the expo of my client.

How to do this? I don't have any idea. Can anyone tell me ALL the correct step to achieve this?

Thanks in advance, Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to setup a kiosk mode. You can find a good tutorial and all needed steps at http://www.alandmoore.com/blog/2011/11/05/creating-a-kiosk-with-linux-and-x11-2011-edition/

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be what i'm looking for. But i need to investigate more. 
However, is this the best praticse? What if i create a user without rights, home and shell and on login i auto open google chrome?
This because the pc, need to run some process in background and display the result via Chrome, it has not any kind of internet connection. Just display data in a web page, and the possibility to login as admin on startup to collect data or admin the sistem

Answer (score 0):

This may be an "old hat" answer...but yes, it's pretty common in practice to simply create a login shell that does a specific task (kind of similar to FTP or backup user accounts).

This means - simply put - in the /etc/passwd where you normally put the shell for the user (/bin/bash or whatever) you actually put a script that does whatever you want it to. When the script ends, the user is booted off.

If this is combined with a properly configured selinux, its pretty safe as long as the script is not hackable (I.e. does not request input which can have appended commands (I.e. "input name:" Mike; rm -rf /) or that can lead to a buffer overrun.

For this reason, its good practice to put the script in an isolated directory, chroot the user, put the user in its own group, and have the user/group only have permissions to that dir.